# How can I make chrome extension script still work even if pop up is closed?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, web, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension and in a part of the script for the extension it refreshes the page. The problem is when it refreshes the page the pop up closes and the script stops completely and you have to start over from the beginning. How can I fix this so that the script will work even if the pop up is closed?

Comment: Either open the popup in a separate window or split the logic into the [background script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) and use messaging for coordination.

Comment: How does a background script work @wOxxOm

Comment: It just works. See the documentation and the official [demo extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples).